# Can you triangulate a position without knowledge of distance?

Tags: geometry

So, here's the set up. You've got 3 points on a 2D plane, and one object to be located. The object is never within the triangle that 3 points make. You are given knowledge of which point is closest to the object.

Is there a way to find distance to the object using the information presented? If not, how many points would be required, would you never be able to get the distance, without more information?

I imagine that the more points you add, the smaller the 'cone' pointing to the object is, but I don't think you can get the actual distance.

(This is just something I thought about while playing a game. It seemed like a mathy type of question, so I asked it here.)

Comment: Given any finite set of points, the "closest" relation will give you finite many criterion to determine position, you can never use them to resolve all points because there are infinitely many of them!

Comment: You can try a [Voronoi tessellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) of the plane based on the known points, but unless the "closest known point" is strictly inside the convex hull of the known points (it is not with a triangle) then there is no limit on the possible distance of the unknown point.  [Triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation_(surveying)) is slightly different as it involves measuring angles

Comment: @Henry Yeah. I meant to air quote the "triangulate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picture shows the Voronoi domains of a set of points, i.e. the loci of points that are closer to a given point of the set than to any other (cells separated by gray edges).

If you exclude all points that are inside a red triangle, what remains is a set of infinite domains, and obviously the distance is indeterminate.

[image]

Comment: That's essentially what I expected. I've got to read up on this Voronoi tessellation. Looks cool.

Comment: There are three little areas outside the red triangles in your diagram which are part of finite grey cells

Comment: @Henry: yes that can happen.

Comment: This is what I was hinting at when I said *the "closest known point" is strictly inside the convex hull of the known points* in my comment on the question